# Using a conditional comprehesion and the re.search function to find all the strings in a list?

Tags: python, list, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use a conditional comprehesion and the re.search function to find all the strings in DNA_list that start with 'ATG' and end with 'TAG'

```
DNA_list = ['GTCTCTCGA', 'ATGCCTGAAGCATTCTAG', 'GCTGCCCACAAG', 'ATGACTGTAAAACCCTAG']
import re
dna=[print(element)for element in DNA_list if re.search(r'(^ATG)(TAG$)',str(DNA_list))]
```

But I don't get an output. What am I missing?

Comment: You want `if re.search(r'(^ATG)(TAG$)', element)`. As an aside, you should **not** use list comprehensions for side-effects, ie for printing. List comprehensions are for building lists.

Comment: Also, you are going to want to change your regex to `r'(^ATG).*(TAG$)'` Because without `.*` it will **only** match `ATGTAG`

Comment: Also, building a list of `None` (because `print` returns `None`) doesn't really seem that productive.

Comment: I'd probably use `str.startswith` and `str.endswith` here.  `[item for item in DNA_list if item.startwith('ATG') and item.endswith('TAG')]`

Comment: My desired output is '['ATGCCTGAAGCATTCTAG', 'ATGACTGTAAAACCCTAG']'

Answer (score 1):

```
result = [s for s in DNA_list if re.match(r'^ATG.*TAG$', s)]
```